# ios default location detection

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

Hi I have implemented an app that has some location based information.

However if a location is not found some of the services become a bit buggy so what I am trying to do is that if a location is not found it defaults to a certain point.

Is there a way to set it up with CLLocationManager in iOS8?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have sample code that you are trying to build and is not working. I can take a loot at it

Comment: "...what I am trying to do is that if a location is not found it defaults to a certain point." Huh? I have no idea what that means. You need to be clear and specific about what you are trying to do. Are you trying to simulate location manager readings so you can test your code?

Comment: Sorry for some policies of the company I can't share code, what I need is that if the location manager of the phone cannot give me a gps signal (for any reason) I would set the default location to a certain point in the map. This wouldn't be for debugging only also for release. For Example:
if(self,locationinfo.location == nil){
    //set default location
}

Comment: You have a couple of options, assuming that you have some property in which you store your current location, either initialise it to the default and then allow the location update to update it naturally or start a timer and if you haven't had a location update before it fires, set the location to your default. You cannot get the CLLocationManager itself to return a default location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to set a default location to CLLocationManager since it is a read-only value. However I was able to set the camera to zoom to a specific location if the location manager wasn't working. Also if your location manager is not working all the time in the simulation, don't freak out: [CLLocationManager not working all the time (iOS 8, Xcode 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081646/cllocationmanager-not-working-all-the-time-ios-8-xcode-6)
it should work fine on your device.